# Code for recognizing what page the Fragment is on?

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewpagerindicator

Hi there I am trying to find the code that will recognize what page I am on the moment and if I am on a certain page that I want something to happen. I need all this code to be in every single one of my Fragment Activity as I want to change the title of the Action Bar as the user swipes through these Fragments so therefore I will need a code that can perform this type of function. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your fragments to change the title of the actionbar as they are presented you can do this in the onViewCreated method of a fragment.

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        activity.setTitle(R.string.my_desired_title);
        /* You can also do this
         * activity.getActionbar().setTitle("myTitle");
         */
    }
```

Comment: sorry but I have tried this and this does not work as I have multiple fragments ?

Comment: I see so you have multiple fragments on screen. Which fragment would be the one to change the title ? Would it be the one the user  is currently touching ?